# How to draw a full box around a Mayavi mlab plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mayavi.mlab

I am making a 3D contour plot of some volumetric data using `mlab` from the Mayavi module. I would like to draw a box with the axes around that plot, but I am only able to get one x-axis, one y-axis, and one z-axis. The axes opposite of those axes are not drawn. How do I get those missing axes?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import mayavi
import sys

# check versions
print( 'matplotlib version: ', matplotlib.__version__ )
print( 'mayavi version    : ', mayavi.__version__ )
print( 'numpy version     : ', np.__version__ )
print( 'python version    : ', sys.version_info )

# create the grid
x       = np.linspace(0,np.pi,100)
y       = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
z       = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,400)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

# create the data to be plotted
dat = np.cos(X) * np.sin(Y) * np.cos(Z)

# make a 3D contour plot
mlab.contour3d(dat)
ax1 = mlab.axes( color=(1,1,1), nb_labels=4 )
mlab.show()
```

The output of the version check is as follows:

```
matplotlib version:  3.5.0
mayavi version    :  4.7.4
numpy version     :  1.21.4
python version    :  sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

And, finally, the image, where it can be seen clearly that there is no full box surrounding the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple: `mlab.outline()`. One has to replace the contour plotting part with the following code:

```
# make a 3D contour plot
cont3d  = mlab.contour3d(dat)
ax1     = mlab.axes( color=(1,1,1), nb_labels=4 )
mlab.outline(cont3d)
mlab.show()
```